# COUNT field not set during pagination in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-pagination

i have created an API end-point using with custom method. This returns a paginated response. but when i try to get response after filtering records i get following error.

> **lib/python3.6/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 575, in execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
> django.db.utils.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')**

Following is code snippet that i am using to return paginated response.

Code:

```
data_dict= request.data

for k,v in data_dict.items():
    my_filter("{0}_{1}".format(k, "in")]=v

obj=Master.objects.filter(**my_filter) 

page = self.paginate_queryset(obj) 

if page is not None:
    serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True) 
    return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data) 

return Response({})
```